# command to return model file name

Tags: netlogo

Apologies if I have missed this in the documentation.

Is there a command to return the current model file name? i.e. "model2.nlogo"

I am writing some output functions and would like to include the model name from which results were produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather belatedly, I added a primitive to the pathdir extension, `pathdir:get-model-name`, that will return the name of the current model, or an empty string if it is still "Untitled".  You can get to the extension through the "Extensions" link on the NetLogo Home Page.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. (An extension could do it.)